Google Calendar API Events : list not displaying dateTime Information
I want to go through all events of a Google Calendar and do some operations based on the start and end time of each event. I use Celigo as a plattform to export all calendar meetings and then do operations on them.
I use the following API Call:
.../calendar/v3/calendars/*****/events?timeMin=2024-09-20T10:00:00Z&timeMax=2024-11-03T10:00:00Z&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&maxResults=50&showHiddenInvitations=true

Which generally works and returns all Calendar Events for the bleeped out calendar address, however the information is not displayed in full.
I am expecting the field "start" and "end" to contain Information regarding the specific time the event starts and ends.
The Doc (Goolge Calendar Events) says the returned field should look like this
"start": {
    "date": date,
    "dateTime": datetime,
    "timeZone": string
  }

However instead this is returned:
"start": {
    "date": "2024-09-20"
  }

Why does the API call only return the date but not the time of the start and end of the event?
There are a lot of other fields missing as well, for example the field "creator" should display
"creator": {
  "id": string,
  "email": string,
  "displayName": string,
  "self": boolean
}

but only "email" is returned
The API Explorer you can use in the docs also only returns the date and not the time.

This event is probably an "all-day" event? And for the missing fields in creator: the docs say "if available", so those other fields may not be available

Oh you're right, they were "all-day" events! We usually have a lot more non-all-day events. so I didn't even consider it a possibility that all returned events happened to be all-day
